# How many divisor $x^2$ has which are less than $x$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$x=2^55^3$. 
How many positive divisors of $x^2$ are there less than $x$?

I counted $38$ but I don't know how to start without counting.

Comment: Please comment about how you got your answer. Hopefully we can help clarify.

Comment: It is actually not an answer. Just checked its divisors.  Can you give me a hint

Comment: Hint: if $ab = n^2$, then $a < n$ if and only if $b > n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$x^2=2^{10}\times 5^6$ has $11\times 7=77$ divisors including the square root
$x=2^5\times 5^3$.

There are $76$ divisors of $x^2$ different from $x$.

Exactly the half of them are less than x, the other half of them greater than $x$.

So, the solution is $38$.

Comment: Paul Sinclair's hint helps to understand that the half of divisors are less than and the other half greater than $x$.